# Why do I continue to have stale data in my useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My `useEffect` is running as it should be, but once it is complete, it doesn't update the state of my Component. It always shows the previous render. I thought I have added all the appropriate dependencies, but it still gives me stale data. Here is my hook:

```
export default function useSort(items, sortKey, sortAscending) {
  let [sorted, setSorted] = useState(items);

  useEffect(() => {
    let sortedItems = sortKey ? items.sort((a, b) => {
      if (!a[sortKey] && b[sortKey]) return sortAscending ? -1 : 1;
      if (a[sortKey] && !b[sortKey]) return sortAscending ? 1 : -1;
      if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) return sortAscending ? 1 : -1;
      if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) return sortAscending ? -1 : 1;
      return 0;
    }) : items;
     setSorted(sortedItems);
  }, [items, sortKey, sortAscending]);

  return sorted;
}
```

Here is the component I am using it in:

```
const SearchResults = ({ columns, searchResults, sortAscending, sortKey }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let sorted = useSort(searchResults, sortKey, sortAscending);

  return sorted.map((searchResult, index) => {
    return ( ... )
  }
```

`SearchResult` renders, but when I try to sort the results (depending on the column header I click), the `useEffect` code runs. After it is sorted, `SearchResult` never gets re-rendered to show the change.

How am I using the hook incorrectly? What is the proper usage?

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem but `sort` is *in-place*, so it could be interfering with change detection.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but should be noted that from Rules of Hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level "Only Call Hooks at the Top Level", You have a condition `if (!sortKey) return sorted;` this will prevent useEffect from being run consistently. If you use other hooks after useEffect, this might cause unpredictable behaviours

Comment: I agree. That `if` statement was breaking one of the rules of hooks. I updated the code. You were also correct in it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: try setting ```sorted``` as a dependency.

Comment: I can try that, but the issue isn't that the `useEffect` isn't running, it is. The issue is that once the `useEffect` is complete and the data is sorted, the Component doesn't re-render.

Comment: I tried adding `sorted` as a dependency and it didn't work.

Comment: You are mutating `items` - you should work on the copy of that array I would check if this solves the issue with useEffect, because it can.

Comment: How is `items` being mutated? I am sorting it, but that just returns a new array. What am I missing?

Comment: @jhamm it doesn't return a new array, as said by jonrsharpe in the first comment.

Comment: So I changed my code to `[...items].sort()` and it is working? Why do we have to return a new array? Please submit as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript are `reference` type; and `setState` will cause re-render of the component when current value and previous values being different; unlike primitive types, reference types will only marked as changed when their reference change (i.e. shallow comparison). In this scenario when you mutate the array in-place, previous value and next value would be the same from shallow comparison perspective; it's like calling `setState(2)` when the `state` is already `2`; reconciliation will ignore that. people already mention that in the comments if you return new array (new reference), that would fix it; by the way check out the snippet below for a specific show-case of the problem happening here:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById("root"))

function Test(){
    const [array, setArray] = React.useState([2,3,4,5]);
    const renderCounter = React.useRef(0);
    
    function mutateInPlace(e){
        renderCounter.current++;
        // some random in-place mutations
        array[1] = 4;
        array[2] = 11;
        array.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
        setArray(array);
    }
    
    function mutateOutOfPlace(e) {
        renderCounter.current++;
        // creating a new array
        let arrayCopy = array.slice(0);
        setArray(arrayCopy);
    }
    
    console.log("re-rendered");
    return (
        <div>
            {renderCounter.current}
            <br/>
            <button onClick={mutateInPlace}>mutate in-place</button>
            <button onClick={mutateOutOfPlace}>mutate out-of-place</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```